# How do I find and replace text using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt, replace, find

Using XSLT 2.0, I need to replace:

```
<section class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude">
```

with:

```
<section class="ktp-explanation-section atom-exclude">
```

But in all instances EXCEPT when the span tag below exists:

```
<span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">behavioral_sciences</span>
```

I'm not very good with XLST. What would I need to include in my XSLT script to make that happen?

Here's an example of the HTML with the behavioral_sciences tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ktp-question-set"
    data-uuid="90dcafa425ef42dca522211db2db1f1f">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>mbeh01001</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set" data-uuid="0b866e6990f940e8b22d8083bff94248">
            <li id="mbeh01001" property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question"
                data-uuid="3e34491dfadd46b58de842471aafd503" class="ktp-question">
                <section class="ktp-question-meta" data-uuid="01e5e879ddda4f4889f1378655a4a3bd">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"
                        data-uuid="e7e38b9d85e045b4a7e6492b2f286cdb">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta"
                            data-value="mbeh01001"></span>
                        <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">behavioral_sciences</span>
                    </section>
                </section>           

                    <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:step"
                        data-title="Step-by-Step" class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude"
                        data-uuid="3a797b95cdc746bdbe73cd69790c21e7">
                        <ol class="list-step-stacked" data-uuid="78b16f9f99a84c00b142739badcc6d13">
                            <li data-uuid="c801e37e13304bbabd807a7aeb06e0ae"><span
                                    class="step-title">Simplify the question</span>
                                <p data-uuid="1a69def59a1448ba973f4953f6cdadf4">The most important
                                    keyword in the question stem that hints at the correct answer is
                                        <i>anthropologist</i>—one who studies the fate of human
                                    beings and thus their reproduction and survival. The
                                    anthropologist correlates the development of a standard set of
                                    emotions with better communication, thereby suggesting that
                                    standard emotions influenced human survival and
                                    reproduction.&#160; Another way of wording the question would
                                    therefore be: <i>Which term best illustrates a positive
                                        influence on human survival and reproduction?</i></p>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </section>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's an example without the behavioral_sciences tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ktp-question-set"
    data-uuid="90dcafa425ef42dca522211db2db1f1f">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>mbeh01001</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set" data-uuid="0b866e6990f940e8b22d8083bff94248">
            <li id="mbeh01001" property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question"
                data-uuid="3e34491dfadd46b58de842471aafd503" class="ktp-question">
                <section class="ktp-question-meta" data-uuid="01e5e879ddda4f4889f1378655a4a3bd">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"
                        data-uuid="e7e38b9d85e045b4a7e6492b2f286cdb">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta"
                            data-value="mbeh01001"></span>
                        <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">biology</span>
                    </section>
                </section>           

                    <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:step"
                        data-title="Step-by-Step" class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude"
                        data-uuid="3a797b95cdc746bdbe73cd69790c21e7">
                        <ol class="list-step-stacked" data-uuid="78b16f9f99a84c00b142739badcc6d13">
                            <li data-uuid="c801e37e13304bbabd807a7aeb06e0ae"><span
                                    class="step-title">Simplify the question</span>
                                <p data-uuid="1a69def59a1448ba973f4953f6cdadf4">The most important
                                    keyword in the question stem that hints at the correct answer is
                                        <i>anthropologist</i>—one who studies the fate of human
                                    beings and thus their reproduction and survival. The
                                    anthropologist correlates the development of a standard set of
                                    emotions with better communication, thereby suggesting that
                                    standard emotions influenced human survival and
                                    reproduction.&#160; Another way of wording the question would
                                    therefore be: <i>Which term best illustrates a positive
                                        influence on human survival and reproduction?</i></p>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </section>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show an example of XML input that contains both cases, along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section/@class[.='ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude' and not(//span[@property='atom:tag' and @class='ktp-meta' and .='behavioral_sciences'])]">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">ktp-explanation-section atom-exclude</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this tests for the presence of `<span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">behavioral_sciences</span>` in the entire document, unrelated to the matched `class` attribute.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! The only question I have is the top metadata section is outputting with the self-ending span tag. The system we use needs the </span> tag. How can that be adjusted?

Comment: Try changing the output method to `html`?

Comment: I changed the output to HTML but that stopped me from getting anything to output. It's giving me an error saying Unsupported HTML version: 1.0.

Comment: Well, naturally. Either change the version to something reasonable (e.g.`4.0` or `5.0`) or remove the `version` attribute altogether.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!